# AJAX searchbox shows part of source code on textbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a live search system for a Cellphone comparison website. I have the phones stored in a table on MySQL and with a variable called "completename" and "id". The "completename" variable is for showing the complete name on the results and the id is for creating the link to the specific cellphone.

The code works, I type a name and it shows similar results in the table. If I type Sony, it will show up to 5 phones that contain the word Sony in its name.

What i Want to do is to convert those results in links so they are clickable and send the user to the respective phone info viewer.

Here's the code for the searchbox:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10
});
});
</script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="bs-example">
    <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
</div>
```

And here's for search.php:

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
$db=mysql_select_db("database",$con);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phones where completename LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $array[] = '<a href="viewer.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['completename'] . '</a>';
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

My problem is that when I click the result, which is a link and works, for a moment, while the request is being sent by the browser, in the search textbox I can see the source code that is in the $array variable (the

So, how can I prevent this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: shouldn't be sending back html. Use the plugin API to render the links. See example in docs. WHen you make selection it will populate the input with whatever property you declare for it